# Create a function that takes in a person object that has a name and an age property

Tags: javascript, function, object

My instruction for this object lesson is to return a concatenation to show that one person is old enough to drive and the other isn't. I have been able to call the function to show that Jeremy is old enough to drive. I need this equation to also be able to somehow also say that Chase is not old enough to drive. I have been working on this for over two days and can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be so appreciated!

```
function canDrive(name, age) {
  var person = {
  name: "Jeremy",
  age: 24,
  };

  if (person.age >= 16) {
    return person.name + " is old enough to drive.";
  }

  else {
    return person.name + " is not old enough to drive.";
  }}

  canDrive();
```

The instruction for this assignment is: 
Create a function called canDrive that takes in a person object that has a name and an age property.

If the person's age is greater than or equal to 16 then return a string concatenating their name with the string " is old enough to drive."

If the person's age is less than 16 then return a string concatenating their name with the string " is not old enough to drive."

Comment: One tip: Your function should look like this: `function canDrive(person) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are close actually, you have written correct logic in the function. Now you just need to pass person object to this function as parameter when you call it. Use only one argument for the function like `canDrive(person)` and use that inside the function. This way you write the function once, and then pass it any person and check for that person.

```js
  var person1 = {
  name: "Jeremy",
  age: 24,
  };

  var person2 = {
  name: "Chase",
  age: 15,
  };

function canDrive(person) {

  if (person.age >= 16) {
return person.name + " is old enough to drive.";
  }

  else {
return person.name + " is not old enough to drive.";
  }
}

  console.log(canDrive(person1));
console.log(canDrive(person2));
```

Comment: Yes! This worked and finally makes some sense! Thank you!